# CSS backdrop-filter blur effect misaligned in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with a fixed height, as well as a child div that extends outside of the parent. Within Chrome 75, this results in the parent div's backdrop-filter effect being applied outside of the expected area. This does not happen with IOS/Safari.

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/7grL6t0n/

Firefox or Edge don't support backdrop filters at all. Not sure about other platforms/browsers.

Please note: You need to have 'Experimental Web Platform features' activated in chrome://flags to see the blur effect.

Is this a Chrome bug or am I doing something wrong. If it is a bug, is there perhaps some CSS workaround for this problem?

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/USAF-1951.svg/1024px-USAF-1951.svg.png);
}

.parent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

.child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Parent with fixed height, red background and "blur" backdrop filter, which should appear within the parent, but is moved down by the child.
    <div class="child">
      Child with green background, extending outsite of parent.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome 75. The backdrop-filter feature was officially launched in Chrome 76, and this bug (and many others) was fixed for the 76 release.